# Changing CCSprite's physicsBody type CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic crashes app

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, game-physics, cocos2d-x-3.0, chipmunk

I have a CCSprite containing more than one **CCSprite** as it's children. All the children sprite's physics body are of type are of type **CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic** primarily. I need to stop the parent CCSprite immediately after pressing a button. So I was making each of them of type **CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic** and again converting their type to **CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic**. But sometimes it crashes the app. Debugger showing the crash at **static void
PairsClear(Node *leaf, cpBBTree *tree)** function of **cpBBTree.c** in Chipmunk physics library.

[image]

and the functions, I used to stop the container sprite immediately were

```
-(void)stop{

    bodySprite.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    collideSprite.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    leftWheel.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    rightwheel.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
}

-(void)startMoving{

    bodySprite.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
    collideSprite.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
    leftWheel.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
    rightwheel.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
}

-(void)moveToLeft{

    // Player's moving direction is going to be changed, going to apply break by stopping the whole body, and then allowing it to move
    if ((currentMovingDirection != MovingDirectionLeft)) {
        currentMovingDirection = MovingDirectionLeft;
        [self applyBreak];
    }

    [leftWheel.physicsBody applyTorque:WheelTorque];
    [rightwheel.physicsBody applyTorque:WheelTorque];
}
-(void)moveToRight{

    // Player's moving direction is going to be changed, going to apply break by stopping the whole body, and then allowing it to move
    if ((currentMovingDirection != MovingDirectionRight)) {
        currentMovingDirection = MovingDirectionRight;
        [self applyBreak];
    }
    [leftWheel.physicsBody applyTorque:-WheelTorque];
    [rightwheel.physicsBody applyTorque:-WheelTorque];

}

-(void)applyBreak{
    [self stop];
    [self startMoving];
}
```

On button click events I was calling **movetoLeft()** to **moveToRight()**. These calls are not from collision delegates.Is there any way to stop the container sprite immediately with it's children or to avoid the crash?

Comment: where do you call the stop method from? If it's from a collision callback you will have to defer it until after the physics world step. Same as you can't remove bodies during collision callback (at least not in the c version of chipmunk).

Comment: The calls are not from any collision delegates, they are invoked from button click events. Commenting the content of the function -(void)stop() is not leading to crash. I need to stop the whole body immediately the -(void)stop function is called.

Comment: button events .. what kind of buttons? Consider that these events may run on a separate thread and could execute during physics world step.

Comment: I think that you should try to set your body's velocity and forces to 0 rather than changing it's type of body.

Comment: That was not working actually, ok solve it with an another silly stupid way. Instead of making all childern static I was applying allowRotation property of each wheel as NO in -(void)stop() and again making them YES in  -(void)startMoving(). That is working perfectly...